A calculation on the canonical connection/curvature of the tautological bundle of Grassmannian
I am reading Wells' Differential Analysis on Complex Manifolds and I am stuck on a calculation about the canonical connection on the tautological bundle of the Grassmannian $U_{r,n} \to G_{r,n}$ on p. 82. The setup is the following:
Let $f = \{e_1, \cdots, e_r\}$ be a holomorphic local frame on some open subset $U \subset G_{r,n}$, so that each $e_j$ is a holomorphic function $U \to \mathbb{C}^n$. Identify $f$ with the full-rank $n \times r$ matrix with columns $e_1, \cdots, e_r$ and define a Hermitian metric $h$ on $U_{r,n}$ (locally) by $h(f) = f^* f$ (where $*$ is conjugate transpose). The canonical connection $D$ on $U_{r,n}$ is defined (locally) by the matrix $\theta(f) := h^{-1}(f) \partial h(f)$. It is established that the curvature $\Theta$ of the canonical connection is given (locally) by $\Theta(f) = \bar{\partial} \theta(f)$. From there, he claims that
$$\Theta(f) = h^{-1} \cdot (df)^* \wedge (df) - h^{-1} \cdot (df)^* \cdot f \cdot h^{-1} \wedge f^* \cdot df$$
(omitting all the annoying references to $f$ for the $h$'s). I believe one should be able to obtain this by applying the properties of $\partial$ and $\bar{\partial}$ but has been stuck for a while now. The only thing I have so far is
$$\Theta(f) = \bar{\partial} (h^{-1} \partial h) = \bar{\partial} (h^{-1} f^* \cdot df)$$
since $\partial f^* = 0$ (for $f^*$ being anti-holomorphic). But I'm not sure, with another application of the Leibniz rule, how to express $\bar{\partial} h^{-1}$ in terms of $h^{-1}$ and $f$. I think I'm making my life way more complicated by using some kind of implicit function theorem (which the book doesn't mention). I am quite terrible at these kind of analytical calculations, so I'm not confident whether I'm on the right track or not. Can someone give me some help?
